# Intellij Scala library dependency not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to Scala & IntelliJ. I am trying to write a JSON program but it has compile errors below. I am using `json4s-core_2.9.1-3.0.0`.

> Error:(37, 14) Class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException not
>   found - continuing with a stub. Error:(37, 14) Class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException not found -
>   continuing with a stub. Error:(37, 14) Class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException not found -
>   continuing with a stub.

In my set file, I have:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
```

libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "{latestVersion}"

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson.core" % "{latestVersion}"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "JsonParseException" % "{latestVersion}"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "JsonProcessingException" % "{latestVersion}"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "JsonGenerationException" % "{latestVersion}"
```

What could go wrong? Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json4s-core_2.9.1-3.0.0` looks like a very dated version that works with Scala 2.9.1 but you are using Scala version 2.12.4. You need the most recent version of `json4s` that works with Scala 2.12.4 (which, based on Maven is [json4s 3.5.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-core)).  From the `json4s` [install instructions](http://json4s.org/) I think you just need the following in your `build.sbt` file.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "{latestVersion}" 
)
```

This should grab the latest version of `json4s-core` automatically along with the `json4s-jackson` libraries.

Comment: Ahh... That is why. I grabbed the update 2.12.3.5.3.

Comment: Great! Please remember to accept the answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Ahh... That is why. I grabbed the update 2.12.3.5.3 and I added "
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-AST" % "{latestVersion}"" to the best file. Now, I get a different error (Symbol 'term org.json4s.JsonAST' is missing from the classpath). Is there a way to figure out? How do you know the dependencies format (like org.json4s or json4s-jackson)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Figured out. The new update has a different set of function parameters. Thank you!